Inadequate behavior of model using verilogA: LS simulation results do not match with expected values from model
I am modeling a power amplifier VerilogA module where two electrical inputs (b0 and b1) define the behavior of its compression point.
In this sense, for example, if [b0, b1] = [0, 0], the compression point is 10 dBm; if [b0, b1] = [1,1], the compression point becomes 20 dBm. The logical zeros and ones are translated from voltages driven by DC sources, instantiated in the workbench and a HB + DC simulations are ran to obtain the results.
I have managed to simulate the module behavior with large signal simulations, however, when inspecting the selection bits and comparing with its respective power mode, the simulation indication of mode and model mode do not match. For example, the code [0,1] should deliver OCP1dB of 30 dBm, however it is mode [1,0] which is delivering such compression point. The problem seems to be some kind of issue when registering the logical signals from the voltage sources, but I'm not sure...
What am I missing?
module PA_PB_V00_R02(in, out, b0, b1, vdd, gnd);
    inout in, out, vdd, gnd;
    input b0, b1; //2 bits to select up to 4 modes
    electrical in, out, vdd, gnd;
    electrical b0, b1;
    parameter real cpdb = 30;

    real cpdbVar = 0;

   analog begin
       @(initial_step) begin

        cpdbVar = cpdb;

        case(1)
            ((V(b1) == 0) && (V(b0) == 0)) : cpdbVar = 5;
            ((V(b1) == 0) && (V(b0) == 1)) : cpdbVar = cpdbVar;
            ((V(b1) == 1) && (V(b0) == 0)) : cpdbVar = cpdbVar - 5;
            ((V(b1) == 1) && (V(b0) == 1)) : cpdbVar = cpdbVar - 10;
            default $strobe("Should not be here - cpdbVar");
        endcase
    
   (The mathematical coding goes here and is proprietary).

   end 
endmodule

